# How to download pptx file from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, powerpoint

I have file path URL as given below

```
http://ccidahra.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/sample.ppt
```

When I open in browser it browser give option to download file. It means URL is correct, also Downloaded file is open so file also correct. But When I try to do same in iOS using code. I am getting error. I have write below code to download file.

```
  NSString *fullURL = @"http://ccidahra.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/sample.ppt";
    NSString *encodedURL = [fullURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURL];

NSLog(@"fullURL %@",fullURL);
NSURLSession *sessions = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [sessions dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSString *docPath = [[AppDelegate documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingString:@"/sample.ppt"];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager ]removeItemAtPath:docPath error:nil];

        }

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"file created ar %@",docPath);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"file can not created ar %@",docPath);
        }
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });

        [AlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" withMessage:@"Service error! Please connect to the internet" inViewController:self];
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

I am getting below error When downloading file.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000253fb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http%3A%2F%2Fccidahra.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F03%2Fsample.ppt, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http%3A%2F%2Fccidahra.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F03%2Fsample.ppt, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

please help me to solve this issue. I want to open ppt, pptx , doc file in UIWebview.

Comment: Why are you percent-encoding the URL?

Comment: The URL might be valid, but the server can also deny your request. When you access the URL in a browser, there's much more that goes on besides just downloading the file (e.g. presenting cookies that indicate what user you're logged in as)

Answer (score 0):

It's already a valid, encoded URL. Don't URL-encode it twice. You're turning the path separators into %2F and the scheme separator into %3A, so it can't find the scheme nor path components anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0 Code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWeb: UIWebView!

let url = URL(string: "Your URL")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        myWeb.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWeb?.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

**Objective C**

```
NSString *urlString = @"Your Url";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _myWeb.scalesPageToFit = true;
    [_myWeb loadRequest:request];
```